# Consultant designed a system that uses email as a webservice

Tags: web-services, email, architecture, anti-patterns

I am looking for some solid arguements against a solution supplied where a public facing webserver hosts an aspx form and based on user input places the content of the form in XML in an email body and sends it to an email address only used for this solution. Then an internal system behind the company firewall reads the XML after retrieving the email from the email server and processes from there. I dont think this will be a robust solution and concerned about maintaining it so would just rather replace it now but there is pressure to keep solution.

Thanks

Comment: This might be on-topic at [programmers.se].

Comment: OTOH it also means there is no public facint service - depending on the company infrastructure that may simply be the best solution. Email is buffered at the provider, "the company internet" can have a moving IP (dsl style) without bothering. I think this is a case of "Programmer wants optimal solution ignoring real world limitations".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *mostly* can't judge an architectural solution without knowing the specific constraints.

Under certain constraints, this may be very well be the best solution.

Let's take a look at the weak points first:

- Messages may be lost due to the mail service not available.
- Messages may be too big for the mail service. (In my corp we have a limit of 10Mb for instance.)
- Messages may be corrupted on transfer. (Mail service may apply virus scanners and boast with this fact, add footers, rename attachments etc.)
- Mail system may not cope with the additional burden, if the message traffic is too big.
- Order of delivery is not guaranteed.
- The solution is somewhat non-conventional.
- Security and other non-func may be not fulfilled.

On the other hand:

- This is probably a (very pragmatic) implementation of asynchronous messaging. Asynchronous messaging is often much more powerful and reliably than synchronous solutions.
- This solution uses an already existing infrastructure.
- Mail system does normally not lose messages "just so". So we basically have a reliable persistent message storage here.
- Mail systems are often considered to be "mission critical" so they're often built highly reliable and redundant. So using the mail service may be actually *more* reliable than introducing a new software/hardware component.
- And cheaper.
- Can be tested with very pragmatic means.
- E-mail has good library support.
- You don't need an expensive professional for implementation.

So imagine the following constraints:

- Build an asynchronous message processing.
- Losing small percentage of messages is not a big deal.
- Do it fast.
- Do it cheap.
- Quick and dirty is OK ("we'll throw it away in three month anyway").

**Under these constraints this might be a very good and pragmatic solution.**

To address the point by @techtrek:

- 1. "far more robust" - see above, mail system may actually be *more* reliable than an internal ESB infrastructure. At least this is my experience.
- 2. Agree, but not THAT risky. Attachments are normally NOT damaged in anyway. Otherwise management would scream every time their PowerPoint slides get corrupted.
- 3. Emails service down - well, ESB or any internal service may go down as well.
- 4. I don't quite understand why e-mail traceability is more complicated. I send an email, it either arrives or not. If not then this is a problem of the mail service. "Complicating" compared to what?
- 5. Well, of course mail service administration is separate, why is this a maintenance headache? We actually have all the platform services (databases, servers, ESB, etc.) administered and maintained by separate teams. This is a normal practice, I don't see why it should be a problem here. On the contrary, with the mail service you probably have a professional team specifically dedicated to the reliability of that transport channel.

Frankly, I saw quite a few ESB/MQ-solutions where I really thought that it would be MUCH cheaper, easier and in the fact more reliable if a few distinct apps would just send each other e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using email as the relay agent is that:

1. Creating a webservice that allows your company's internal system to directly intercept and parse XML system seems far more robust to me.
2. Encapsulating the XML mime type within a transmission protocol (Email) is risky in and of itself.
3. As a result of (2), there are two points of failure (corruption in the xml conversion process) and also the risk of the email service going down.
4. Beyond just points of failure, you're also complicating traceability by an order of magnitude.
5. Email administration is often separate to the administration of the web-service. Unless there are real, legitimate reaosns for this, it just sounds like more maintenance headache?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what has been said, especially on point 4. Application and eMail Maintenance might be disconnected entities.

Another aspect to consider is the possibility ti send mail from anywhere to the backend and flood it this way